# Passing parameters to stored procedure using a SQLCMD batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file

I am attempting to pass some parameters to a SQL Server stored procedure using a `.bat` file but I keep getting an incorrect syntax error.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_TEST 
    (@Username  VARCHAR(20))
WITH ENCRYPTION
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @USERID INT

    SET @USERID = (SELECT flduserid FROM BPOCORE..tblusers WHERE fldusername = @Username)

    UPDATE tbluserdetails 
    SET fldloggedon = 'No' 
    WHERE flduserid = @USERID
END
```

Here is the batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
NEW BATCH

ECHO. 
ECHO Welcome - enter details
ECHO. 

:Login
ECHO Type in the SQL Server and Login Details as noted below:
        ECHO SQLInstance:
        SET /P SQLInstance= 
        ECHO.
        ECHO DatabaseName
        SET /P DatabaseName=
        ECHO.
        ECHO BPOUserName:
        SET /P BPOUserName=
        ECHO.
        ECHO BPOPassword:
        SET /P BPOPassword=
        ECHO.
        ECHO enter_username
                set /v test1 =
        ECHO.

sqlcmd -S %SQLInstance% -d %DatabaseName% -l0 -U %BPOUserName% -P %BPOPassword%  -i c:\sp_TEST.sql -v test1
ECHO.
PAUSE&EXIT
```

I keep getting this error:

> ERROR - Syntax of the command is incorrect

I don't understand why it is failing and reading the documentation is not helping for this specific issue.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I'm not aware of a `NEW` command, is it the name of an executable file with `BATCH` as an argument/parameter? I'm also unaware of a `/V` option for the `SET` command! and there should be no space between the variable name and the `=` character either. So when you read the documentation for `new /?` and `set /?` did you not notice these glaringly obvious issues?

Comment: It would also save you some space were you to use e.g. `SET /P "BPOUserName=BPOUserName: "`, instead of `ECHO BPOUserName:` followed by `SET /P BPOUserName=`.  I would be surprised were that syntax not mentioned in the help information too! What documentation did you read? Did you consider removing the first line, or changing it to `@ECHO ON`, then running the script from an open cmd.exe window, to see where the syntax error was coming from?

Comment: [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#command-line-options)

I was attempting to add a variable using the -v parameter and then setting it using user input, the syntax clearly shows `sqlcmd -v MyVar1=something MyVar2="some thing"` but now how do I set the variable `-v` via user input? 

I have implemented your suggestions.

ERROR - 'test1': Invalid Argument

Comment: The NEW BATCH command is just garbage. Ignore it.

Comment: You are not passing any parameters to a procedure, you are in fact calling a script that performs a `CREATE PROCEDURE`. It is supremely unlikely that's what you want to do. If you just want to call the existing procedure, use the `-Q` option (`-Q "exec sp_TEST @username='%test1%'"`). If for some reason you would want to customize the procedure's creation, you'd use the `$(test1)` syntax to replace the string in the script (and even then you'd use `/v test1=%test1%` syntax, as `sqlcmd` and `cmd` know nothing of each other's variables).

Comment: @TheChannels, you don't need to tell me, it's the command parser which needs to know to ignore it. The easiest way to do that is to make it a comment, i.e. by prepending it with `Rem`, or by deleting it from your script. Did you bother to fix the other issues or advice I mentioned? or are you simply ignoring them? _despite the error message you posted in your question being fixed by doing so_. Open a Command Prompt window and enter `set /v test1 =` if you don't believe me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to deploy (create) the SP in your target database. If c:\sp_TEST.sql contains the SQL of sp_TEST, you are just deploying it, not running it, and no parameters required to create the SP.

-v is to specify sqlcmd parameter, not SP parameter. To call the SP with the given parameter, you need to define a sqlcmd parameter in the sql to call the SP:

```
sqlcmd -S %SQLInstance% -d %DatabaseName% -l0 -U %BPOUserName% -P %BPOPassword%  -Q"EXEC sp_TEST @Username='$(UserName)'" -v UserName="%test1%"
```

Thanks @Jeroen's comments. It also works without using the sqlcmd variable:

```
sqlcmd -S %SQLInstance% -d %DatabaseName% -l0 -U %BPOUserName% -P %BPOPassword%  -Q"EXEC sp_TEST @Username='%test1%'"
```

Comment: It's worth nothing that `$(var)` performs a pure textual replacement and doesn't do anything "sane" for (say) escaping single quotes in an actual parameter. As such this is really only worth doing if you wanted to replace the value multiple times, otherwise it's not any better than `@Username='test1'`.

Comment: It should be:  -v UserName="%test1%"  in the command line. Not sure we directly use the batch variable or not due to the double and single quotes. I will update the answer to add the missing % around the batch variable.

Comment: Just did a quick test, so the query can be changed without using the sqlcmd variable: -Q"EXEC sp_TEST @Username='%test1%'"

Comment: Thank you to all users involved, your comments were fantastic.